# No visible @interface for selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, initialization, declaration

Basically I know where would be normally problem (different method than I declared) but take a look at this. Of course I may be missing something but I have been trying to solve this problem for an hour. I also did clean.

> Error: DetailGymViewController.m:46:62: No visible @interface for 'CustomAnnotation' declares the selector 'initWithCoordinate:title:subtitle:'

Code with error:

```
#import "DetailGymViewController.h"
#import "CustomAnnotation.h"

@interface DetailGymViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailGymViewController {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;



    self.nameLabel.text = self.name;
    self.longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%f"), self.longitude];
    self.latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"%f"), self.latitude];
}

#pragma mark - Map/Locations delegates

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get location with error: %@", error);
}

- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.latitude = self.latitude;
    coordinate.longitude = self.longitude;
    // ERROR HERE
    CustomAnnotation *annotation = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate title:self.name subtitle:@"Info"];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:(id)annotation];
}
```

declaration of CustomAnnotation.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface CustomAnnotation : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic,assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate title:(NSString *)title subtitle:(NSString *)subtitle;

@end
```

also, my CustomAnnotation.m file:

```
        #import "CustomAnnotation.h"

        @implementation CustomAnnotation

        -(id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate title:(NSString *)title subtitle:(NSString *)subtitle {
            if ((self = [super init])) {
                self.coordinate = coordinate;
                self.title = title;
                self.subtitle = subtitle;
            }
            return self;
        }

        @end
```

Comment: Can you check if you've missed adding CustomAnnotation to an application target?

Comment: @ldindu where can I find that? Weird thing is that I am using mentioned init method in another file and I don't get any error

Comment: Where is your `initWithCoordinate` method?

Comment: ok, that means they are added on proper target, then there might some other issue.

Comment: @andrewbuilder in my CustomAnnotation.h file, it is in my post.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes it is, I have posted it in code

Comment: Interesting, apparently if I use only: 
    `CustomAnnotation *annotation = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate title:self.name];`

it gets no error but my app crashes

Comment: It's acting like you don't have the init declaration in the .h, which is strange.  Did you double-check the spelling?  (I realize that sometimes spelling gets changed in the process of copy/pasting the messages and code.)

Comment: @HotLicks Xcode isn't even telling me that this method exists when I start writing a name of a method.

Comment: Somewhere you've got a second @interface for CustomAllocation.

Comment: Very likely there are two CustonAllocation.h files in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know where was problem. I just hit cmd + n by mistake and errors were gone.
I have no idea what just Xcode did.

Comment: You realize, of course, that using Cmd+N causes life as you know it to stop instantaneously and every molecule in your body to explode at the speed of light.